# YOLOV5 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY9w6.png)does anybody know why i got this error when i do mask_detection case with YOLOV5. How can i fix it? thanks for your answer~

I have tried to rewrite the code like shape = np.array(self.anchors[i], p[i]).shape.But it can not solve this issue.

Comment: Please post your error as text, not as image

Comment: I didn't understand did you rewrite the code in loss.py file ?

Comment: I have the same problem when (re)training a yolov5 model with the instructions provided:
`...
    anchors, shape = self.anchors[i], p[i].shape
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
`
using the command `python train.py --img 640 --epochs 3 --data data.yaml --weights yolov5s-seg.pt`

no changes to the `loss.py` or [the repo](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) in general